# How to install ruby on rails in a specific user in Ubuntu 2004?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am trying to install ruby on rails in a user named `Test` in Ubuntu2004 (Windows Subsystem). Following steps in this website: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 
However, I kept getting error from the following step:

```
git clone https://github.com/excid3/asdf.git ~/.asdf
```

Error:

```
fatal: could not create leading directories of '/home/Test/.asdf': Permission denied
```

What should I do to get past this step?

I am hoping someone could walk me through steps I should do to install ruby on rails successfully.

Comment: It's a strange bug, as you should have all permissions on your on home directory...
As a workaround, can you try creating the directory manually (`mkdir ~/.asdf`) before running `git clone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did

sudo -E bash

and solved this issue

Answer (score 2):

It is a permission error.

You just have to run it as an administrator and you are good to go.

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/excid3/asdf.git ~/.asdf
```

Comment: While that might work it's not the optimal solution. He is trying to clone the repository into his home directory, he should already have the necessary permissions.